# GCC stdlib XCode 4.5

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, std

How can I use the GCC stdlib in XCode 4.5? When I write`std::decimal::decimal128 a;` I get an error because for XCode `std` is the Standard C++ Library, not the GCC stdlib.

Any help?

Comment: Oh what? 1. ***This is absolutely unrelated to Xcode.*** 2. There's no such thing as the "GCC stdlib". You probably meant the C standard library (?). 3. Have you tried including the appropriate C++ header file and compiling your source as C++?

Comment: 1. I didn't mean to insult XCode, I love it. 2. This is the library: http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/ 3. What would the headers be, please? 4. Of course I compiled my source as C++.

Comment: `#include <decimal>`, maybe?

Comment: I get a "symbol not found" error, what does that mean? Is my GCC version too old?

Comment: link with `g++` or `gcc -lstdc++`.

Answer (score 1):

For gcc decimal operation are built into the compiler. The C extension specified by [TR 24732](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1312.pdf) is carried over to C++. Although some of the operations are linked from a library, there isn't in any library you can use from another compiler. Thus, I don't think it would help you to use a different standard library. In general, you can change [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s standard C++ library using the `-stdlib=...` option.

At some point there was a public implementation of C++ [TR 24733](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) publically available but it seems not to be accessible at the moment. I'm mildly hopeful that I can provide an open implementation at some point next year but since this is part of my actual work it isn't up to me to decide whether and, if so, when the work can be made available. A basic implementation using, e.g., IBM's [decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html) library is fairly straight forward. Doing a complete implementation is a bit of work, though, even when using decNumber.